# Google app engine : get_by_id not reliable?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a very simple query by `get_by_id` :

```
query = Query().get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))
```

The int(self.request.get('id')) have no problem passing the value.

My problem is that sometime the query work and sometime aren't. When it was not working it show `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'abc'`

Any idea?

Comment: Where is `abc` coming from?  Is Query() from google.appengine.ext.db, or is it a db.Model subclass you've defined?

Comment: this the db.model : `class Query(db.Model): abc = db.StringProperty()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're constructing a new instance of your entity class (`Query` is a poor name for it, by the way), then calling a class method on it. You don't need to do this - just call the class method directly:

```
query = Query.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `google.appengine.ext.db` there is a class called [Query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query) (which doesn't have an `abc` attribute). You might want to change the name of your model, just in case the reference is being resolved incorrectly.