# Google App Engine : alternate method of get_by_id()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

By given an entity ID , I will query by `models = Model.get_by_id(id)`. However, I find out that some time it will not return result collectly.

Is there any alternative or recommended method to query by entity ID in Google App Engine, python?

Comment: What do you mean with "some time it will not return result correctly"?

Comment: by running the models = Model.get_by_id(id) , sometime it will return nothing, and sometime it work perfectly , the "id" is a constant integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google app engine : get_by_id not reliable ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169917/google-app-engine-get-by-id-not-reliable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappear by itself after the 2011-05-10, which is the v1.5 launch date. Not sure this problem is related.

I didn't change any code, as the get_by_id() was fine all the while and on this few days. Beside, I added a cron job to run the get_by_id() every minutes and try to get the instance alive.

From my observation, the get_by_id() failed because it couldn't query the datastore.

Btw, the setting of datastore is Master/Slave Replication.

Answer (score 6):

If you are saving your class instances with a parent then get_by_id will not return the object but instead will return None due to the reason that the key is not complete thus requiring the parent key as well. I encountered the same issue and was a pain in the ass to figure out.

```
ico = Icons.get_by_id("3", parent = parentkey)
```

This will return an object. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If `Model.get_by_id(id)` returns `None`, this indicates that you've supplied an invalid ID, not that the method itself is unreliable.

It's not inconceivable that this method could fail in the event of a system outage, but if it did, your call would throw a datastore exception, not return an empty result.

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't get_by_id(), but rather passing invalid keys or not handling exceptions properly.

Answer (score 0):

`get_by_id()` always get the object, if the passed object is a valid id of object and if the objects exists in the datastore.

id can be got by `object.key.id` in the templat

else you always have the `object.get(key).`